# Gerar query para exibir dados do MySQL em php

Tags: php, mysql

O banco foi criado da seguinte forma:

- Cada Disciplina pode ter 1 ou mais turmas, enquanto cada Turma pertence a somente 1 disciplina.
- Cada Professor pode ter 1 ou mais turmas, enquanto cada Turma pertence a somente 1 professor.
- Cada Aluno pode estar matriculado em 1 ou mais turmas, enquanto uma Turma pode ter 1 ou mais alunos.
- Cada Aluno tem 2 notas por Turma em que está matriculado.

Preciso criar uma página (usando a linguagem PHP) que consulte o banco de dados e mostre as seguintes informações:

- Qual professor tem mais alunos do sexo masculino ('m')
- Qual professor tem mais alunas do sexo feminino ('f')
- Qual turma tem a maior média geral
- Qual turma tem a maior média individual (de apenas 1 aluno)
- Qual turma tem a menor média geral
- Qual turma tem a menor média individual (de apenas 1 aluno)
- Listar o código de cada turma com as seguintes informações associadas a ela: a média geral (de todas as notas), o nome do aluno com a menor média, o nome do aluno com a maior média.

Estou com dúvidas de como gerar essa query no DB e se posso criar uma variável para casa uma delas ?

Comment: Eduardo, você precisa modelar as entidades em banco e montar os comandos SQL realizando join's entre as entidades com a finalidade de obter suas 7 respostas.

Comment: Você já tem algum código feito?